# Como fazer NGinx exibir mensagens de erro em tela do mesmo modo que o Apache faz em vez de '502 bad gateway'

Tags: php, apache, nginx, php-fpm

O NGinx e o Apache apresentam erros de forma diferente quando há um problema na execução de um script PHP. O Apache, quando configurado para exibir em tela, exibe exatamente o erro, com arquivo e linha aonde ele ocorreu, porém o NGinx normalmente exibe apenas algo como **502 bad gateway**.

A maioria das soluções, até mesmo no stackoverflow.com em inglês, no máximo ajudam a configurar o  `NGinx` e o  `PHP-FPM` para direcionar os erros para um arquivo de texto, mas eu pessoalmente não consegui fazer o NGinx exibir os erros *exatamente* como o Apache faria. Entendo que em produção não é ideal exibir erros em tela para o usuário, porém um problema constante ao usar NGinx em vez de Apache para um desenvolvedor testar sua aplicação é que a maioria tem dificuldade em debugar apenas olhando arquivos de logs.

Por *exatamente* especifico que é todos os erros possíveis que teoricamente o NGinx poderia exibir. Caso um worker do php-fpm não esteja ativo ou com problemas sérios seria aceitável ainda ter os mesmos erros

Comment: Algum usuário com pontuação suficiente poderia criar a tag `php-fpm` por favor? Ainda não tem no pt SO.

Answer (score 2):

pode fazer de vários jeitos

```
 error_page 502 /arquivo502.html
```

ou encaminhar a chamada para um pseudo location e tratar pela aplicação

```
error_page 502 @teste
location @teste {
  <faça o que quiser aqui>
}
```

pode haver um erro no php-fpm pois é um proxy... nesse caso pode ajudar evitar que ele encaminhe os erros... ou caso queira tratar... forçar que sejam encaminhados

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
```

Comment: `error_page 502 /arquivo502.html` apenas redirecionaria para um erro diferente, não exibiria o erro. E o que `<faça o que quiser aqui>` de fato deveria ser para exibir os erros reais? Não ficou claro.

Comment: é que no caso especifico do 502 o php-fpm não respondeu a tempo ou não respondeu o cabeçalho corretamente.. então não tem como encaminhar de uma forma elegante o erro que o veio do php... veja o error log do nginx... ele faz o log raw do cgi lá..

Comment: talvez só para manter em desenvolvimento... vc poderia colocar o location encaminhando para um php que prite na tela as ultimas linhas do errolog do nginx... não é bonito... mas vai simplificar o processo...

Answer (score 0):

Se compreendi bem o quer quer é mostrar os erros de execução.

Normalmente com apache você apenas habilita `DISPLAY_ERRORS` no `php.ini` da seguinte maneira.

```
[raiz]php.ini
DISPLAY_ERRORS= ON
```

No meu caso defino mais não funcionar então para tratar o erro sou obrigado a força o PHP exibir os *warnings* com

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```