# 502 Bad Gateway - Linux, php7, nginx. Como resolver esse erro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php-7, nginx, php-fpm

Estou tendo um erro 502 que representa alguma configuração no servidor, quando tento abrir um site usando linux, nginx e php7.
Pesquisando alguns outros [POSTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04), [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4372/como-fazer-nginx-exibir-mensagens-de-erro-em-tela-do-mesmo-modo-que-o-apache-faz) sobre o mesmo erro vejo que o php precisa do fpm para ser reconhecido no nginx. Porém o fpm está instalado e atualizado. Veja foto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo o erro [505](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) tem algo acontecendo no servidor. Não deve ser o php-7 (eu acho).
Alguém tem alguma idéa do que poderia ser?

### Atualizando

E finalmente parece que é um erro devido ao PHP. Testei com um arquivo html e nao tive problemas. Então parece que tem algo com o php mesmo. O que pode ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Últimos logs

```
2016/07/06 06:14:56 [crit] 834#834: *15 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ig.app, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "ig.app"

2016/07/06 06:15:04 [crit] 834#834: *15 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ig.app, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "ig.app"

2016/07/06 06:15:04 [crit] 834#834: *15 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ig.app, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "ig.app"

2016/07/06 06:16:29 [crit] 834#834: *15 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ig.app, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "ig.app"
```

Comment: Pode colar o log do nginx?

Comment: É, parece que ele está procurando um arquivo do php5-fpm e nao está achando. Mas eu estou usando com php-7 que já possui o fpm. Alguma idéia?

Comment: No arquivo de configuração `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` você atualiza  de `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` para `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;`

Comment: isso mesmo. Vc quase acertou. no lugar de mudar na pasta `default` eu mudei na pasta do projeto, no caso `ig.app.conf`. Uma nota: na instalação do php7 do linux 16.04 LTS através do  `apt install php-dev ` ou  `apt install php ` (que no linux 16.04 vai instalar php7.0 como default), notar que depois da pasta `/var/run/` ainda existe mais um diretorio `/php`. Ou seja, o caminho completo é `/var/run/php/php7-fpm.sock` e não  `/var/run/php7-fpm.sock`. POsta sua resposta para receber os créditos.

Comment: Muito bom! :) Coloque isso como resposta porque alguém procurando por esse problema na página principal vai ver que não resposta e pode nem clicar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx se comunica com PHP-FPM usando um soquete de domínio Unix. Sockets mapeiam para um caminho no sistema de ar.

Versão 5.x do PHP usava o caminho `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

Deve ficar assim:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5-fpm.sock;
```

Já para PHP7.x o caminho é esse `/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock` (exemplo, troque o `.4` por outra se sua versão for diferente) e deve ficar assim:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

[image: Exemplo da configuração para PHP7.x]

A configuração do site pode ser encontrada em diferentes pastas dependendo do sistema que usa. Então pesquise caso não encontre.
Nesta resposta usaremos um dos caminhos padrões.

Para editar o arquivo de configuração você pode usar `nano` (ou outro editor), é necessário usar `sudo/su` (dependendo se é baseado em Debian ou em Ubuntu), exemplo:

```
> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

As configurações do SOCKET podem variar devido a versão do NGINX, como também a versão do sistema operacional. A versão do PHP pode também interferir.
Caso o seu servidor não tenha nenhuma referencia em arquivos padrão.
Pesquise sempre citando o sistema operacional.
Note que a "versão" do Socket é sempre alterada, juntamente com a versão do PHP-FPM. Mas não necessariamente o numero como no exemplo deve estar presente.